# jquery method parent() with multitag doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to delete with a link `<a href="#" class="removeclass">remove row</a>` 
the row below:

```
$(AddButton).click(function (e)  //on add input button click
{

        FieldCount++; //text box added increment
        //add input box
        var menu = '<td><input....></td>';
        var numPortata = '<td><input...></td>';
        var quantita = '<td><input......></td>';
       // THIS IS THE ROW 
$(InputsWrapper).append('<tr><td><a href="#" class="removeclass"><b>&times;</b></a></td>'+ menu + numPortata + quantita +'</tr>');
        x++; //text box increment
return false;
});

$("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    if( x > 1 ) {
            $(this).parent('tr').remove(); //remove text box
            x--; //decrement textbox
    }
return false;
})
```

by clicking in the link until i were using only a `div` and not a `tr` it worked fine.
But i need tu use a table for do that so why changing from a unique `<div>` to a table with rows and cells don't work?

What i need to edit? I tried to put in the `.parent()` in place of `tr` i've tried `td` and obviously it delete the `&times;` (×), but not the rest. How to delete the whole tr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

[.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) will find only the direct parent element, in this case the `td` element since it does not match the passed selector `tr` the method will not return any element. Instead you want to find the ancestor `tr` element so you need to use `.closest()`